# awk: Selecting rows based on the first 3 different values of a given column

Tags: linux, unix, awk, gawk

I'd like to read **fileIn.txt** (comma delimited) and output **fileOut.txt** with only rows that match the first 3 different values of a given column. For example, my input file looks like this:

```
fileIn.txt
#location,day,time
home,mon,01:00
office,mon,06:00
home,mon,10:00
office,tues,03:00
home,wed,08:00
home,wed,11:00
home,thurs,02:00
home,fri,01:00
diner,fri,07:00
party,fri,09:00
home,sat,02:00
mall,sat,06:00
home,sat,09:00
beach,sun,01:00
```

I want to select only the rows with the first 3 different days, so that my output file looks like this:

```
fileOut.txt
#location,day,time
home,mon,01:00
office,mon,06:00
home,mon,10:00
office,tues,03:00
home,wed,08:00
home,wed,11:00
```

Comment: Can it be assumed the input file is already sorted?

Comment: Yes, you can assume so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little confusing. But if I understand right you want to print out any row that has a day of the week matching one of whatever the first 3 distinct values the script finds in the file. You could do that with awk like so

```
BEGIN { FS="," }

{
    if(dayCount < 3 && !($2 in days)) { days[$2] = 1; ++dayCount }
    if ($2 in days) { print }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue! 
including the header in a more idiomatic form.

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1{c[$2]} length(c)<4{c[$2]} $2 in c' file

#location,day,time
home,mon,01:00
office,mon,06:00
home,mon,10:00
office,tues,03:00
home,wed,08:00
home,wed,11:00
```

**Explanation:** first block initialize the array with the first row value, since cannot check the length of an array before it's initialized. Array `c` contains the distinct $2 fields and we keep adding until the size reaches 4 in the second block (that is, with the header there will be 4 distinct values).  In the final block, check whether the row is one of the distinct values and print (as the default action).

I didn't want to make it more cryptic but you can merge the first two blocks since the actions are identical

```
$ awk -F, 'NR==1 || length(c)<4 {c[$2]} $2 in c' file
```

it depends on the short circuited logic operations to not evaluate length until after it's initialized for `NR==1`.

Comment: You wizard... Can you possibly decipher that for us newbs?

Comment: woah, yes please . . .

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F, '
    /^#/            {print; next}   # keep comments
    ++seen[$2] == 1 {count++}       # incr counter the first time value is seen
    count > 3       {exit}          # quit if we have seen 4 values
                    {print}         # otherwise print this line
' file
```